# How to delete neighboring duplicate pixels from an image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a project with images in python, the result has to be a one pixel wide segmentation.

The results are very good but in some images it happens that the width is two pixels. How could this redundancy be erased?

Below I show some of the problems:

[image: Overlap in horizontal image]

[image: Overlap in vertical image]

[image: Overlap in vertical and horizontal image]

Comment: Maybe, [`skimage.morphology.skeletonize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html) is helpful?

Comment: or [`erode`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb)?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).